# Webpack warning after building the bundle (critical dependencies)

Tags: node.js, webpack

[image]webpack throwing these warning after building bundle

```
WARNING in ./~/openlayers/dist/ol.js
Critical dependencies:
292:366-373 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/openlayers/dist/ol.js 292:366-373
WARNING in ./~/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js
Critical dependencies:
12380:444-451 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js 12380:444-451
```

Configrations :

[image]

app structure :
[image]

**update**
how can i ignore files in warning message with `noparse` 
any suggestions?

Comment: webopack 1.14.0 @Codesingh

Comment: i think your code is returning non-zero error code

Comment: @Codesingh take a look on the screenshot in the question

Comment: do you have webpack validator?

Comment: no what is that /

Comment: before giving you a link

Comment: tell me are you using gulp with webpack?

Comment: i think it's `DEPRECATED` [link](https://github.com/kentcdodds/webpack-validator-DEPRECATED)

Comment: please go through this https://github.com/js-dxtools/webpack-validator#schema

Comment: Try ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress --colors --config conf/webpack.config.js --bail

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: wait i am working on it

Comment: use this : /webpack --colors --config config/webpack/production.config.js --json --bail 2>&1

Comment: command used by you ?

Comment: webpack -d --bail --colors --progress

Comment: is it working for you ?

Comment: @Codesingh okay now i realized that i can not make Webpack ignore `ol.js` from parsing process